# Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am a newbie in Fortran programming. I know this error may due to wrong data type, but I do not know which correct data type I should choose for...

Here is my code:

```
program main
REAL                :: tempo(3), temp
INTEGER             :: num_sta, num_sou

num_sta = 0
num_sou = 0
OPEN(11,status="old",file="sou_location.txt")
OPEN(12,status="old",file="sta_location.txt")
OPEN(21,file="RESULTS.txt")

DO WHILE ( .NOT. eof(11) )
  READ(11,*) tempo(:)
  num_sou = num_sou + 1
END DO
REWIND(11)

DO WHILE ( .NOT. eof(12) )
  READ(12,*) tempo(:)
  num_sta = num_sta + 1
END DO
REWIND(12)
end program main
```

and here is the error message:

```
eew_loca_H_test.f90:11:18:

DO WHILE ( .NOT. eof(11) )
               1
Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)
eew_loca_H_test.f90:17:18:

DO WHILE ( .NOT. eof(12) )
               1
Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is REAL(4)
```

Comment: What is your `eof`? It looks like it is not defined anywhere (do you come from Pascal?). You want a LOGICAL expressiin there.

Comment: And use IMPLICIT NONE, it is very important.

Comment: Are you expecting that this was once compiled by a compiler which offered an `eof` intrinsic function?

Comment: @francescalus Yes, that is what I thought. I have changed to IS_IOSTAT_END, but it keeps showing "At line 14 of file eew_loca_H_test.f90 (unit = 11, file = 'sou_location.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file" now...

Comment: You mean you have, say, `is_iostat_end(11)` now instead of `eof(11)`?  `is_iostat_end(11)` will always return `.FALSE.`: you'll need to use an `iostat=` specifier in your `read`s and pass the corresponding variable to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOF is a nonstandard intrinsic function that is probably not supported by the compiler you are using. The compilers I know of that do support this have EOF returning type LOGICAL, which is what your program expects. Otherwise Fortran implicit typing makes this REAL, which is an error for a logical operator such as .NOT.. (Some compilers won't warn you about this unless you ask for standards checking.) @francescalus has the right answer - include an IOSTAT= specifier in the READ and use IS_IOSTAT_EOF(statvar) to test it. You'll want to initialize "statvar" (or whatever you call it) to 0 before the loop, and be sure to declare it as INTEGER.